# Ubuntu Server auto start irssi in proxy mode

Tags: server, irssi

On my home server I use irssi in proxy mode to keep track of irc.  From any of my desktops I then just point xchat to my home server.

What I want to be able to do is have irssi start in my user session on the server and start in proxy mode.  I've read everything I can find about this but had no joy running it, can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

The [first hit on google](http://michael.lustfield.net/content/irssi-proxy) provides all information needed:

Add this line to `/etc/rc.local` (using administrator privileges):

```
sudo -H -u USER screen -d -m -S irssi-proxy irssi
```

Replace USER with your username. Explanation of the command:

```
sudo ; runs command as user
-H ; sets the home directory to the users
-u ; sets the command to act as USER
screen ; the command sudo is executing
-d -m ; starts screen detached. This solves a lot of issues later.
-S ; starts the screen session with the irssi-proxy ID.
irssi ; the command we're launching
```

You will have to install `screen` to make this work (screen is a very nice little tool to run command line applications in the background).

If you want to get your irssi in the foreground later you can do that by running `screen -r irssi-proxy` in a terminal.

Alternatively you can use crontab to have it run as boot (saves you from changing system files in /etc):

Run `crontab -e` as your User. Add this line:

```
@reboot screen -d -m -S irssi-proxy irssi
```

It will basically have the same affect as the entry in rc.local.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I have tried the issue I have is this start irssi but not the proxy server element you still have to go in and manually start the proxy bit.  I'll keep digging but thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Did you see this line in the blog post? `You want to proxy to load my default so edit ~/.irssi/startup and addthe line "/LOAD PROXY".`

Comment: Yeap doesn't seem to trigger anything for me which is where my frustration stems from.  I might try digging into it some more this weekend and see if I can't sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer.

```
vim .irssi/startup
```

Then add the line

```
LOAD proxy
```

This now loads the proxy correctly \o/

Answer (score 0):

from [Irssi Documentation](http://www.irssi.org/documentation/proxy)

**Irssi proxy usage:**

First you'll need to have the proxy module installed, either configure
irssi with --with-proxy and do make install, or manually:

```
cd src/irc/proxy
  make
  mkdir ~/.irssi/modules
  cp .libs/libproxy.so ~/.irssi/modules/
```

In irssi, say:

```
 /LOAD proxy
```

You really should set some password for the proxy with:

```
/SET irssiproxy_password secret
```

Then you'll need to configure the `ports/ircnets` the proxy listens in,
something like:

```
/SET irssiproxy_ports ircnet=2777 efnet=2778 freenode=2779
```

There we have 3 different irc networks answering in 3 ports. Note that
you'll have to make the correct /`IRCNET ADD` and `/SERVER ADD` commands to
make it work properly.

hope thats helps you.

Comment: If he is already using it in proxy mode he most probably already did all this. The question is how to have it started automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Starting irssi in rc.local does not work. The Interface is not up.
Starting in cron  also does not work. The interface is not up.
You have to start irssi in /etc/network/if-up.d/ with a little Script.